# How to read data for non-ndef NFC tag with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, nfc

Using phonegap/cordova, how can I read the data of an NFC tag that is not in NDEF format?

I'm using [phonegap-nfc plugin](http://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) for Android.

Here's how I get the id of the tag :

```
nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
    function(nfcEvent){
        console.log(nfcEvent.tag.id);
    },
    function() {
        console.log("Listening for NFC tags.");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("NFC activation failed.");
    }
);
```

How to get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported by that phonegap-nfc plugin.